# Why is this module not being seen by my Perl script?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that starts like so (it was written by someone who no longer works here, but it has been modified several times since then):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

BEGIN
{
    use File::Basename;
    my ($scriptname, $dirname, $extension) = fileparse ($0, ".pl");

    push (@INC, ("$dirname/../../shared/lib"));
    push (@INC, ("$dirname/../../shared/lib/DBA"));
}


use strict;
use File::Path;
use File::Basename;
use Getopt::Std;
use Cwd 'realpath';
use DBA;
use DBA::MySQL;
use dba_functions;
```

The modules 'DBA.pm' and 'DBA/MySQL.pm' work fine. But the dba_functions module, which exists in the same directory as DBA.pm, while giving no errors when `use`d, does not appear to be loaded. A call to any sub within that module complains about a non-existent subroutine. The module is used in many other scripts within our environment and works fine.

Now, both DBA.pm and DBA/MySQL.pm have an object-oriented design, while dba_functions.pm is merely a collection of subroutines. For example, DBA.pm starts like this:

```
package DBA;

use 5.008;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;
use DBI;
use Fcntl qw (:flock);
use Term::ReadKey;
use DBA::MySQL;
use DBA::Config;
use DBA::MessageLogger;
use DBA::Util qw(rearrange make_attributes);
use Date::Format;
use File::Path;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;
use File::Basename;
use vars qw($VERSION);
use User::pwent;

our $VERSION = '0.01';

BEGIN
{
    use File::Basename;
    use Cwd 'realpath';
    push (@INC, realpath(dirname($0) . "/../../shared/lib"));
}

use Cwd 'realpath';
require "dba_functions.pl";

sub new
{
    my ($class, @p) = @_;
```

(dba_functions.pl is an older, obsolete version of dba_functions.pm, but I haven't been able to switch to using the new version because of this problem)

dba_functions.pm starts like this:

```
require Exporter;

use strict;
use warnings;
#use ServiceNow;
#use ServiceNow::Configuration;
use LWP;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @export = qw(date
             @pfiles
             dba_archive_file
             dba_distribute_file
             dba_force_update_puppet
[list of subroutines]
use DBI;
use Net::SMTP;
use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use Data::Dumper;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::AES;
use Errno qw(EAGAIN);
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
use Cwd 'realpath';

use constant MYSQL_HOME => "/opt/mysql/instance";
[more constant definitions]
[variable definitions]

sub subroutine_name($;$) {
etc.
```

I'm assuming there's something in one of the other modules that's causing this one not to work, but I have no idea what. This problem happens with other script that call these modules as well.

Comment: Are you sure that the `our @export` in dba_functions.pm` shouldn't be `our @EXPORT`?

Comment: Hmm, that looks like it may be the issue. But why did it work as written in all my other scripts that don't call DBA.pm and MySQL.pm?

Comment: Maybe you `require`d it rather than `use`ing it in the other places.

Comment: Nope, always `use`d it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that the `our @export` statement in `dba_functions.pm` should actually be `our @EXPORT`. Case is important to Perl.